# Grails - preventing validation on a collection?

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

Is there any way to prevent validation of the objects in a collection in Grails (without disabling deep validation)?

I tried using a custom validator on the collection field, but it appears that GORM will validate the individual items in the collection even if you return true in the custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to turn off deep validation as an optional parameter (deepValidate) to your validation call and it's also possible to specify which fields to validate. I recommend looking at the [validation documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) for examples on both.